# Modify an OnClick handler in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a call to an `onclick` that is already created before.
The button already has an `onclick`, but I need to add one more parameter before it does the submit.

Here's the **View Source Code** on the button:

```
<td valign='top' align='right' >
  <button name="Complete"  title="Complete"
   onClick="document.forms.Maker.action='http://example.com:8080/internal/Step.jsp?theId=19032&target=step20&type=Full';
   document.forms.Maker.submit();return false;">Complete</button>
</td>
```

This is a **modification** I made to add a confirmation after the user presses the button, and I also added so it shows what the `onclick` currently has:

```
function addEventConfirmation(element, type){ 
  var old = element['on' + type] || function() {};
  element['on' + type] = function () { 

  if (confirm("Are you sure?")){
    old.call(this);  
    alert(old);
    } else { return false; }
  };
}
```

This is the **alert** from the before code:

```
function onclick()
{
document.forms.Maker.action='http://example.com:8080/internal/Step.jsp?theId=19032&
target=step20&type=Full';document.forms.Maker.submit();return false;
}
```

The **result** should show something like this:

```
function onclick()
{
document.forms.Maker.action='http://example.com:8080/internal/Step.jsp?theId=19032&
target=step20&type=Full&newParam=true';document.forms.Maker.submit();return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: make the action value a variable.

```
var oldURI = "http://mysite.com:8080..."
var href = "oldURI" + "&newParam=true"

document.forms.Maker.action='href'
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, get the Action into a variable. But the onclick object won't let me convert it to String.

Answer (score 0):

If this Html is **your own code**, do just like this :

```
document.getElementById('Complete').onclick = function()
{
    document.forms.Maker.action=
          'http://mysite.com:8080/internal/Step.jsp?theId=19032&
           target=step20&type=Full&newParam=true';
    document.forms.Maker.submit();
    return false;
}
```

else if you are trying to change this event handler from **others website** do this :
put website in an iframe named 'myframe' and code like this :

```
document.getElementById('Complete').onclick = function()
{
    document.forms.Maker.action=
          'http://mysite.com:8080/internal/Step.jsp?theId=19032&
           target=step20&type=Full&newParam=true';
    document.forms.Maker.submit();
    return false;
}
```

but remember to turn cross-domain data source access restriction of your browser off !!!

for example in ie :
Internet Options -> Security -> Custom Settings (Internet Zone) ->

**Enable Access data sources across domains**

Comment: It's not my code, it gets rendered, the values in the parameters may change. So I need to add it at the end, regardless of what the other parameters have.  Also, I don't control the browsers, so can't use that last one.